# How do I position a YouTube iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe, github-pages, youtube-iframe-api

I am trying to center the YouTube video but am having trouble. Here is the code.

```
 <div class="video">
<iframe width="560" height="315" align="middle" padding-bottom=0px left=40px src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lHv3i9-2a0s" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
```

You can find the files (html and css) at the repository below.
https://github.com/t0091/bootstrap/tree/master/home

Comment: Putting `width: 560px; margin: 0 auto;` on the `#video` div does the trick.

Comment: I tried that if I understand you correctly.

Check the bottom of the CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

You can set iframe as

```
iframe{
  margin:0 auto;
  display:block;
}
```

```css
iframe{
  margin:0 auto;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="video">
<iframe width="560" height="315"  align="middle" padding-bottom=0px left=40px src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lHv3i9-2a0s" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
```